# Third Party Android Library Format

Tags: android, android-library

I have downloaded a lot of libraries from Github. When I want to add it in android studio, there's no .jar file in every library I have. Why is it that it has no jar file ? How do I add those libraries in android studio?

Comment: What kinds of libraries are they? Are they pure Java? Or are some Android-specific?

Comment: Android specific. Example is the Boom Menu Library. what should I do to add them to my project?

Comment: I suggest that you start with the README file. It explains exactly how to use the library. Usually you just add a line to your gradle build file as I state in my answer below.

Comment: See my edited answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, you should find the correct line to add to the `dependencies` block in your `build.gradle` file. For example, look at the [README](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu/blob/master/README.md) for the Boom Menu library which you mentioned in your comment. Under the heading [Gradle & Maven](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu/blob/master/README.md#gradle--maven), you see

```
compile 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.0'
```

Add this line to the `dependencies` block in `build.gradle`, sync Android Studio, and then use the library as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

> libraries from GitHub... Example is the Boom Menu library

[This one?](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu) ... Well, you're just [not reading the documentation](https://github.com/Nightonke/BoomMenu#gradle--maven)

Otherwise, if there isn't a [**BinTray**](https://bintray.com/nightonke/maven/boommenu) dependency.

This is exactly what [**JitPack**](https://jitpack.io/) is for

> To get a Git project into your build:
>
> **Step 1**. Add the JitPack repository to your build file
>
> Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:
>
> ```
>    allprojects {
>       repositories {
>           ...
>           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
>       }
>   }
> ```
>
> **Step 2**. Add the dependency
>
> ```
>   dependencies {      
>        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'     
>    }
> ```

Regarding your questions

> Why is it that it has no jar file ?

Because GitHub isn't meant for storing (potentially large) binaries of compiled code, and many Android libraries prefer BinTray over GitHub releases.

> How do I add those libraries in android studio?

You could clone them directly into your project

```
app/
  build.gradle
library/
  build.gradle
settings.gradle
build.gradle
```

In settings.gradle

```
include :app, :library
```

In app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":library")
}
```